# Cannot run flutter: Error (Xcode): ../../Library/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:1102:9: Error: Expected ';' after this

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, frameworks, flutter-dependencies

From yesterday, I am unable to run **any flutter app**, even the new Flutter boiler code app.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a new Flutter project
2. Run and debug main.dart file without changing boiler code
3. Error appers

iOS simulation error:

```
../../Library/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:1102:9: Error: Expected ';' after this
```

Android simulation error:

```
../../Library/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:1102:9: Error: Expected ';' after this.
        01throw FlutterError.fromParts(<DiagnosticsNode>[
        ^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
Process 'command '/Users/anapimolodec/Library/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Please help T.T

I already tried `flutter upgrade`, `flutter clean`
`flutter doctor`: No issues found!

PLEASE ANYONE HEEEELP ~~~

I am expecting being able to run flutter without errors.

Comment: My first guess would be that you accidentally edited that file in the Flutter SDK and introduced a typo.  Have you tried reinstalling the Flutter SDK (or doing `git reset --hard` from the Flutter SDK directory)?

Comment: i have the same problem how did you solve this ?